# Can't push project to GitHub because “unrelated histories” with different URL

Tags: git, github, repository, push

My project is on GitHub at the link https://github.com/sunithacatty/Capstone_p.

I'm unable to resolve an issue with trying push files from capstone_p to GitHub. It's showing as pull and and I'm getting the following error after clicking on pull.

```
From https://github.com/sunithacatty/Htmlproject
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I have no idea how this got created: https://github.com/sunithacatty/Htmlproject

Answer (score 0):

Capstone_p and Htmlproject are two different repositories, you are probably trying to push changes of one repository to another repository so they don't match.

First you need to clone or pull the Capstone_t to your PC, after you cloned it to your PC, add your changes to this repository, add them to the staging area, commit and push

In the console:

1. Go to the desired location for the repository in your PC
2. git clone https://github.com/sunithacatty/Capstone_p.git
3. code, make your changes
4. git add .         (this adds all the changed files to the staging area for the commit, don't forget the dot)
5. git commit -m "commit message here"
6. git push

Comment: I did its still showing same error. I have kept my Capstone_p file in Htmlproject file i guess it created two repositories?                                                                                                                Im getting this erorr because of that ? From           
https://github.com/sunithacatty/Htmlproject
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories                                                                       
How should i delete  Htmlproject.?

Comment: Where are the two projects located in your PC? I guess one of them is inside the other so it's happening, make sure you clone to a completely different path and add your changes there